# regular expressions - only allow letters, numbers and a few symbols?

Tags: regex

i am a newbe to RE but seems that if you only allow letters, numbers and a few symbols that nothing unseemly would get by.

"^[-a-zA-Z0-9_:,.' ']{1,100}$"

as the ?, & and ; and all other symbols are not allowed seems that a query add in or ? could not be created.

i leave in ' for names (O'Henry), etc and will allow & in company names (O'Henry & James), but really check before writing to db and could do a replace characters to a * or something.

what am i missing?

tnx in advance

Comment: Perfectly valid regex, until you talk about writing stuff to the database. Databases have their own escaping mechanism exposed to you in your library (be it escaping values, or using parametrized queries). Don't _alter_ data to get it in the database, it _will_ come back to haunt you.

Comment: What if my name has a slash in it? Or a non-ASCII character?

Comment: Filtering out evil (as opposed to filtering out everything but good) often results in vulnerabilities.  Better to follow Wrikken's advice of using placeholders if you can.

Comment: Just use a function to escape that's designed for your database... that will be much more secure and useful than building your own.